# Padding a Pandas Dataframe with Entries Based on Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
            Amount
Date              
2013-12-31  140.99
2014-01-31   24.97
2014-02-28   30.69
2014-03-31    0.00
2014-04-30    0.00
2014-05-31    0.00
2014-06-30    0.00
2014-07-31    0.00
2014-08-31  183.71
2014-09-30    0.00
2014-10-31    0.00
2014-11-30   59.87
2014-12-31   26.92
Expense
```

This was generated by a `*df.resample("M", how="sum")*` command.

Which in turn was generated by a `*df = df[df["Date"] < end_date]*` command (and additionally, the `*Date*` column was made the index).

My problem:

> The `*end_date*` is March 1, 2015.
>
> However, the dataframe has no entry after 2014-12-31.
>
> I need to have entries like 2015-01-01 and 2015-02-01 (they could be NaN, in which case I'll use `*fillna*` to set them to 0).

How can I have these entries generated (algorithmically - I'm doing this on several datasets and each one ends on a different month so I can't fill them in by hand)?

I need to do this on both ends, actually (beginning and end).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there is an easier way than this, but this isn't too hard.  Assuming your 'Date' index is a datetime, you can just create a date range and append that.

```
In [26]: rng = pd.date_range('1/31/2015', periods=3, freq='1m')

In [27]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Amount': 0 * len(rng) }, index=rng )

In [28]: df.append(df2)
Out[28]: 
                     Amount
2013-12-31           140.99
2014-01-31            24.97
2014-02-28            30.69
2014-03-31             0.00
2014-04-30             0.00
2014-05-31             0.00
2014-06-30             0.00
2014-07-31             0.00
2014-08-31           183.71
2014-09-30             0.00
2014-10-31             0.00
2014-11-30            59.87
2014-12-31            26.92
2015-01-31 00:00:00    0.00
2015-02-28 00:00:00    0.00
2015-03-31 00:00:00    0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

another way, similar to @JohnE's answer, is to just do:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2013-09-30', datetime.date.today(), freq='M')
res = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
res['Amount'] = your_df.Amount
```

Comment: FYI, I changed my method from merge-based to append-based.  Your way looks like a simpler way to merge -- essentially doing an outer join implicitly -- but it didn't quite work when I tried it.   I got all nans for amount...

Comment: are the indices of both dataframes actual `Timestamp` objects? if you have `date` and `Timestamp` or something like that, it won't work.

Comment: Not sure as I didn't save the code, but that's probably it.  I'm pretty sure I used the ```to_datetime``` conversion to attempt to replicate the OP's dataframe (after reading his table via ```read_csv```).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is more comfortable to use pd.concat.
If you need fixed periods in your result time index you don't need to get the last datetime value from your existing index and calculate number of periods to add.

```
periods_number = 100
rng = pd.date_range(0, periods=periods_number, freq='M')
df_padding = pd.DataFrame({ 'dummy': 0 * len(rng) }, index=rng)
result_df = pd.concat([target_df, df_padding], axis=1).fillna(0).drop(columns='dummy')
```